# Remove all duplicate data only show unique

Tags: pandas

I have a data set:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('email_list.csv')
new_data = data[['Email Address','First Name','Last Name']]

            Email Address         First Name       Last Name
0               zoe@gmail.com                Zoé          Z
1              yvonne@yahoo.com            Yvonne         T
2             Whitney@gmail.com           Whitney         W
3                 zoe@gmail.com               Zoe         Z
4              yvonne@yahoo.com            Yvonne         T
```

I want the output to only show me unique emails and names. So from the short list above the output should be:

```
  Email Address             First Name     Last Name
1 Whitney@gmail.com           Whitney         W
```

How can I do this? The simplest way will be best.

Comment: Don't forget that you can also up vote the answers to show additional gratitude by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are searching for:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

`drop_duplicates` remove dupes in your dataframe. The powerful `keep` argument let you tune what to keep and what to drop. If the argument is false, all dupes are dropped.